# What's Pending in AdMob Mediation

Tags: android, admob, inmobi

I created an Android App and Integrated AdMob, inMobi and mMedia SDKs in it, and I used AdMob Mediation to serve ads to my app. When I go to AdMob Mediatio page and open an adUnit, its says "Pending" for both inMobi and mMedia. the question is: 
1) What's this "Pending"? 
2) Do mMedia and inMobi ads serve to my app? 
3) Should I do something else for my app? 
any other suggestions, I will be grateful

Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 10):

> 1) What's this "Pending"?

Essentially you have to register each app with AdMob, InMobi and mMedia. These companies verify each app before you can use their SDKs. This process usually takes couple of days. That's why it says "pending". Just double check that you have followed all instructions correctly. If you've added a faulty URL your app can be stuck in pending stage.

> 2) Do mMedia and InMobi ads serve to my app?

YES!

> 3) Should I do something else for my app?

I'm assuming the app is live on the app store. If yes, then you should be ready to start serving ads on your app once its verified.

I work at InMobi so if you have any other questions, do let me know :)

Comment: I'm implementing Mediation in Android and a bit confused, that after implementing the SDK of InMobi what should I write in xml and java file for Interstitial?